# Doubts about two results about orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

From the textbook book I learnt that the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{R}(A)$ along $\mathcal{R}(A)^\perp$ is $AA^+$, i.e., $P_{\mathcal{R}(A)}=AA^+$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a linear transformation.

However, I am wondering why this is true. Someone says that this is related to the linear least square solution to the equation $Ax=b$, but I could not see this directly from this formula.

Similarly, the textbook provide this result $P_{\mathcal{N}(A)}=I-A^+A$, I have similar doubts about this result.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that obvious from the definition, but once you dig into the proofs, you will see it is correct. If you care about the infinite-dimensional case when the range of $A$ is closed, then check out, e.g., Section 3.2 in Bauschke-Combettes *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces* (second edition, Springer 2017). If you are content in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then read Section 7.4 in Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra* (fifth edition, SIAM 2016).